# Run audio files on a .jar

Tags: java, audio, jar

Good evening, please someone could tell me how the audio files are executed in a .jar

I have tried to call them using getClass (). GetResource () but I can not use it since an error appears.

This is my implementation for playing sounds:

```
public class Sonido extends Thread {

private Clip sonido;

private boolean seguir;

public Sonido(String rutaArchivo){        
    try {

        sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();

        sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(rutaArchivo)));

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(PanelBotones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

 }

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
public void run() {

    seguir = true;

    do {

        sonido.loop(0);

        try {

            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {

            Logger.getLogger(PanelBotones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    interruptedException);

        }

    } while (seguir == true && sonido.isActive());

    // Se cierra el clip.
    sonido.close();

}

public void parar() {

    seguir = false;

   }

}
```

And this is the event method where you created the new clip

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String cadena = e.getActionCommand();

    if (cadena.equalsIgnoreCase(ROJO)) {

        interfazPrincipal.imagenUno();

        sonido = new Sonido("./recursos/sonido/rojo.wav");

        Thread cancionFondo;

        cancionFondo = new Thread(sonido);

        cancionFondo.start();


    }
```

I would be appreciated for your help, thank you.

Comment: What error appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:
`sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sonido.class.getClassLoader().getResource(rutaArchivo)));`

`sonido = new Sonido("my/package/rojo.wav");`